# Uploading files to Sharepoint 2010 Picture Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am creating a iphone app that connects to a sharepoint site to download and upload images.
i can download images by using sharepoint's listdata.svc with GET request and querying the site to retrieve the url of the image that i want.

```
https://xx.xxx.xx/sites/XXX-XXX/xxxx/TestLibrary/1/Picture%20Library/test.jpg
```

Question is how do i upload a file using HTTP PUT request?

Answer (score 0):

Use `_vti_bin/copy.asmx` web-service

Comment: is copy.asmx REST compatible?